# How to get reCAPTCHA token to send to curl request

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

I'm trying to test my backend service which takes a Google reCAPTCHA token and verifies it before proceeding with the request, but each time I want to curl my backend service's endpoint I have to go to the site that is hosting the captcha checkbox, open the network tab in Chrome, click the button, and then manually copy the token from the response into my curl request. Is there a better/easier way to do this? I was hoping that the admin console might have something to help but I don't see anything in there.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript you can get reCAPTCHA response by following

```
let grecaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
```